# Replacing column values using CASE in PostgreSQL 11.0

Tags: postgresql, case

I have following table in PostgreSQL 11.0.

```
col1    col2
1       antagonist
2       antagonist; inhibitor
3       agonist; stimulator
4       inhibitor
5       agonist; inhibitor
```

I would like to create another column with values in col2 replaced as shown below

```
col1    col2                      col3
1       antagonist                inhibitor
2       antagonist; inhibitor     inhibitor, inhibitor
3       agonist; stimulator       activator, activator
4       inhibitor                 inhibitor
5       agonist; inhibitor        activator; inhibitor
```

```sql
select col1,
       case when col2 in (antagonist, inhibitor) then inhibitor
       case when col2 in (agonist, stimulator) then activator
```

How can I deal with a case shown in row5 (activator; inhibitor) or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you store 2 values separated by a ; in a single column?

Comment: That's how it is stored in the current db.

Comment: Looks like a simple `replace()` would do the job

Comment: I understand that this is your current situation. But I also know that this is one of the worst things you can do to a database. I would fix this problem first, before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mtJCZXfcfLiUa7d7dhWuH7/0))

```
select col1,col2,
replace(replace(replace(replace(col2,'antagonist', 'inhibitor'),'agonist','activator'),'stimulator','activator'),';',',') as col3
from test
```